# json.stringify not working on IE8 and below, json2.js used

Tags: json, web-services, internet-explorer, .post, stringify

Below is my code. It works great on IE8 and above, also on chrome and FF... earlier i was getting json undefined i used json2.js now i'm getting alert

```
"something went wrong pls try again"...
```

why is it not going in success..also is there any way to check the json response on IE8 and below from server?

```
$.post(serURL + '/saveForm', {'postdata': JSON.stringify(postJson)}, function(postRes){
  parsedData = jQuery.parseJSON(postRes);
  if (parsedData.Response.Header.Message == 'Success') 
  {
    alert("success")
  } 
 else {
    alert('Something went wrong pls try again..');
  }
}).error(function () 
  {
  alert("webservice issue");
})
```

Comment: You can check the response by hitting F12 in IE and there go to "Network" tab and press "Start Capturing" before executing your request

Comment: @GregOks -thanks for your advice but does IE8 have a network tab in developer tools??